# xamarin forms streaming and recording audio

Tags: audio, xamarin, streaming

I have an app that I have written using Xamarin forms. I wanted to know if there is any media
class I could use to record audio as well as stream audio from a server. All articles I have found on the web are platform specific so far.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There currently isn't any audio support in Xamarin.Forms.  You will need to write platform specific code for handling the audio and use the XF [DependencyService](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/dependency-service/) (or something similar) to call it from your shared code.